# No bibliography in PDF R Markdown output despite .bib file

Tags: reference, r-markdown, bibliography

I writing a document in R Markdown and want to add a bibliography using a `.bib` file created by `Citava`. My basic file is as follows:

```
---
title: "Some text"
bibliography: Test4.bib
---

Some Text

# References
```

If I knit my document the references at the end of the document are missing in the pdf output. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Do you actually refer to any of the files in the bibliography within the text? Only references referred to by the format `[@reference]` will be shown

Comment: @MikeyHarper Okay and what i have to change to see all entrys of the bib file no matter if i reference them in the text or not

Comment: The nocite argument is useful: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html

Comment: As a general tip BTW, it is good to make questions on StackOverflow as minimal as possible. In this example, there is no need to include all the extra LaTeX packges or options within `pdf_document`. It makes it easier for others if you strip the question of any such details (and is also a good way for you to troubleshoot the problem yourself).

Comment: @MikeyHarper thanks for your help. Is there andy faster way to do this. I mean if i would have 40 articeles  i must write them all by hand in the r markdown document what is rly time consuming

Comment: I hope the answer helps: please upvote and mark as accepted if so :) . I have edited the question to highlight how to make a better minimal example. As a side note, if you are writing your thesis in R Markdown, I would strongly recommend bookdown as it allows you to easily split the file into multiple RMD files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R Markdown will by default only display the bibliography for items cited in the text, as shown [here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html).

As outlined in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1096), you can force the display of all items in a bibligraphy by using `nocite: '@*'`. The following reproducible example creates an example `test.bib` containing two bibliography entries, and no reference is made to these directly within the text:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
bibliography: test.bib
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
knitr::write_bib(x = c("rmarkdown", "knitr"), file = "test.bib")
```

Text in which I make no reference to any bibliography.

# References

---
nocite: '@*'
...
````

[image]